# PL/SQL procedure for loop though a table and change values

Tags: oracle, for-loop, plsql, rows

Basically I need to make a for loop that will loop though the amount of rows. In each row I need to check a value and change it if it meets the requirements.

I'm new to Oracle, so I just started building it one step at a time and I'm stuck on looping through the table rows. I need to first get the number count of the rows that a Boolean flag set to 0 (false). So then I can loop through only those rows, not every row in the table. Once I'm done with whatever I need to change in that row, set the flag to 1 (true), so when I run the procedure again it won't include that row.

Here's what I have so far:

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table_results (
  name  varchar,
  account number, 
  address varchar, 
  database_search NUMBER(1) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL

 CONSTRAINT searched_in_database CHECK (database_search IN (0,1))
);
```

The table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table_accounts (
  name  varchar,
  account number, 
  address varchar, 
);
```

Now the procedure will go though the results table and see if the address match, if they do it will copy the account number from the database table into the results account number, then change the flag from 0 to 1, so the next time I search though the table it won't include it because it was already searched.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE FIND_MATCH_ADDRESS AS
BEGIN

DECLARE

   v_cnt NUMBER;

BEGIN

   FOR i IN (SELECT rowid, r.* FROM test_table
           WHERE database_searched = 0)
   LOOP
     LOOP
        SELECT COUNT(1) INTO v_cnt
        FROM test_table
        WHERE database_searched = 0;
  
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_cnt);
     END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;

END FIND_MATCH_ADDRESS;
```

EDIT: Added the two tables in hopes to make my question/task more understandable.

Again thank you for your time!!

Comment: Are you sure you need to use PL/SQL? This: "In each row I need to check a value and change it if it meets the requirements" sounds as if everything can be done using a single UPDATE statement, but - in order to suggest something, you should provide a test case - CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO sample rows, explain algorithm that leads from what you have to what you want, and desired result. As of code you wrote: it doesn't contain much, regarding what you described. Where is that Boolean? What is the inner loop used for? Where's the UPDATE statement? Basically, I don't know how to *improve* it.

Comment: I added the tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example I see some mistakes.

In the procedure you do not need `Declare`. Declaration block is between `as` and `begin`

```
create or replace PROCEDURE proc
AS
  -- here variable declaration or local function or procedures
BEGIN
 -- here you can write a business logic
END proc;
```

You can iterate over the records of a table with a For loop. In your example, you also tried to use them. You can iterate over the records of a table with a `For` loop. In your example, you also tried to use them.

```
FOR record IN (cursor)
LOOP
   {...statements...}
END LOOP;
```

I did not quite understand why you used another loop in the loop. a `loop` statement is an endless loop.

```
loop
  ...
end loop;
```

In the loop you can now implement your logic. If you really want to use a loop, then your solution might look like this

```
create or replace PROCEDURE FIND_MATCH_ADDRESS 
AS
   v_cnt NUMBER;
BEGIN

   FOR rec IN (SELECT r.name
                   ,r.address
                   ,r.account
                   ,a.account as new_account
               FROM test_table_results  r
               join test_table_accounts  a on a.address = r.address 
              WHERE r.database_searched = 0)
   LOOP


     update test_table_results 
        set account = rec.new_account 
          , database_searched = true
      where account = rec.account
        and name = rec.name
        and adress = rec.adress;

   END LOOP;

END FIND_MATCH_ADDRESS;
```

Alternatively, you can also do that with an update. Since I do not know your tables, you should then optimize the where condition.

```
update test_table_results t
set database_searched = true
  , account = (select account 
                from test_table_accounts a
                where a.account = t.account
                  and a.name = t.name
                  and a.adress = t.adress)
where database_searched = false
and exists(select 1 
             from test_table_accounts  a
            where a.account = t.account
            and a.name = t.name
            and a.adress = t.adress);
```

Comment: in my FOR i IN (SELECT rowid, r.* FROM test_table WHERE database_searched = 0) giving me an error. Is select rowid, r.* from <table> the correct way of setting the for loop count to the number of rows in a table?

Comment: @JacobLoncar What is the error? what do you mean by *"to the number of rows in a table"*. In the loop you go through all the records your cursor returns. if you only want to go through certain entries, then you have to adjust your select so that it only delivers the entries that you need

Comment: I added a bit more to the question, sorry very new to this and it might be my fault because I don't know how to ask the question I need answered.

Comment: thank you my good sir!! The reason why I want to do the loop is because I need it to be purposefully slow. Loop will go though each row and do it one at a time which is slower. Thank you for including the update statement too, helped with my understanding